# error while creating dynamic button and how to add click event dynamically without using id

Tags: javascript

```
var shoplink=  $("<button></button>")
               .prop("id",i)
               .val("view more")
               .css({
                     width: '20px'
                     height: '20px'
               });
```

when I used this button js file is not working.I want to add click events for button dynamically without using id.

Comment: can i see the html code ?

Comment: where do you exactly put this code? please provide more info( script and markup).

Comment: new to this field so only asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS function params worng, you missed `,` and `button` have `value` attr for form data only so you should use `text()` function instead of `val()`

```
.css({
 width: '20px' ,
height: '20px' /\
});             |----------------
```

Try this

```
 var shoplink=$("<button></button>")
    .prop("id","idBUTTON")
    .text("view more")
    .css({
     width: '20px',
    height: '20px'
    });
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/yFXkF/1/)

Comment: <button type="button" value="aa" onclick="alert($(this).val())">Click Me!</button> check this button have  attr value

Comment: @Unknownman thanks for comment, I've been updated answer, but OP want to show button text only.

Answer (score 0):

try with comma

```
var shoplink = $('<button></button>')
               .prop('id',i)
               .val('view more')
               .css( { width : '20px',height : '20px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add comma when you define multiple css properties.

```
var shoplink=$("<button></button>")
.prop("id","asdasdasd")
.text("view more")
.val("view more")
.css({ "width": "20px", "height": "20px" });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t74Qg/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
  var shoplink=$("<button></button>")
    .prop("id",i)
    .val("view more")
    .css({
  width: '20px',
  height: '20px'
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ready(function () {

var shoplink=$("<button>")
.prop("id","sad")
.val("view more")
.html("Test")
.css({
 width: '100px',
height: '20px'
});

$("#test").append(shoplink);
 });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="test" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```